# Why is my UIBeizerPath object not drawing in the same rect bounds as my CALayer object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

What I am trying to do is draw a frame around a view using the `UIBezierPath` drawRectWithRounderCorners method. So what I decided to do was take the rect from the draw rect method, apply a `UIEdgesInset` object with values that are negative and try to draw it like that. So far the `UIBezierPath` object is not drawing outside the bounds of the rect passed to draw rect. When I apply the same rect to a `CALayer` object the layer gets drawn as I would need. So how come I can't get the `UIBezierPath` object to draw the same rectangle as the `CALayer` object?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
               UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5,-5, -5, -5)) 
           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];

    [[UIColor blueColor]setFill];
    [[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    [path fill];

    CALayer *backGround = [CALayer layer];
    [backGround setOpacity:.2];
    [backGround setFrame:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, 
                                   UIEdgeInsetsMake(-5,-5, -5, -5))];
    [backGround setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    [self.layer addSublayer:backGround];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A view cannot draw outside of its own bounds.  That's why your `UIBezierPath` doesn't show up.

A layer can draw outside of its superlayer's bounds if the superlayer's `maskstoBounds` property is NO.  The `masksToBounds` property corresponds to the view's `clipsToBounds` property, and the default value is `NO`.